# How do i retrieve files from ftp over HTTPs with python3

Tags: python, https, ftp

I am trying to retrieve files over and https connection using python and i cant seem to find any answers that work with my case

Ive tried using ftplib and FTP_TLS but im getting errors saying that my connection is refused. I log in using my provided credentials and am able to navigate to the actual folder.

```py
>>> ftp = FTP_TLS('HOSTNAME')
>>> ftp.login('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD')
'230 User logged in, proceed.'
>>> ftp.prot_p()
'200 Command PROT okay.'
>>> ftp.cwd('outbox')
'250 Directory changed to /outbox'
>>> ftp.nlst()
Traceback ():
  output
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

Unsure why im getting this when everything else has been successful but i am unable to access the files

Comment: I'm not confident in this suggestion, so I'm not going to post it as an answer, but try the following `ftp = FTP_TLS(host='my-host', user='username', passwd='my-passwd')`. I've always had luck using this, rather than connecting to the host and subsequently calling the `login` method. If this works, let me know and I'll post it as an answer and remove this comment.

Comment: I also tend to use the [retrbinary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrbinary) method: `ftp.retrbinary(filename, open_file_object.write)` to do the actual download.

Comment: @That1Guy unfortunately this didnt work :(

Comment: Ok, but how? Does it give the same error or a different one?

Comment: @That1Guy, yea its the same error

Answer (score 0):

I think your FTP server is configured to return an IP address that is not reachable by the Python script. Once a server reply comes to your Python script, the Python library tries to send data to a host that it doesn't have a route to (or maybe it doesn't even exist).

Some GUI programs try to mitigate that by ignoring the server's IP replies and using the hostname that the user entered during login, but libraries don't do that.

Check this: https://stumbles.id.au/python-ftps-and-mis-configured-servers.html